# React Redux - Sharing state between reducers (reducers hierarchy)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Saying i have an expedia-like search bar tabs:

[image]

I want some of the fields (like **Departing** and **Returning** dates) to be common to all tabs.

So my state should look something like

```
{
  commonReducer: {
    startDate:
    endDate: 
  },
  hotelsReducer: {
    rooms: [],
    location: []
  },
  flightsReducer: {
    from:
    to:
  }
  etc...
}
```

Where the `commonReducer` data is shared between all other tab reducers, since when they click the search button, all reducers should be aware of the selected dates, along with their specific data.

Is there a way to share data between reducers? or have some kind of hierarchy like:

```
{
  searchTabsReducer: {
    commonReducer: {
      startDate:
      endDate: 
    },
    hotelsReducer: {
      rooms: [],
      location: []
    },
    flightsReducer: {
      from:
      to:
    }
    etc...
  }
}
```

So that the `searchTabsReducer` would handle all submits (since he's the only one that has the full picture of the search tabs state)?

From what i understand, the [combine reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) function does not support hierarchy.

I ended up having one way too large file that contains all of the tabs states, but that doesn't feel right.

Thanks.

Comment: I ran into the same problem a whole ago, but I realized that I can get all the state data in the container so I kept the reducers "clean" of hierarchies and combined the data container level.

Comment: You mean the conatiner dispatched the data to the reducer?

Comment: Nope. I kept the reducers as is and mixed the data in the container, feeding it to the component. This does not solve your problem, it avoids it.

Comment: Ah, and also, I do use thunk to have actions that create other actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to combine the reducers, just connect the state from the reducers you need to the containers you want to display the data in.

From there, use that data to dispatch actions, for example your search action.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing data between reducers only requires to create independant reducer. A reducer is always available in other reducers.

Using redux, all data from the application state is available in all [reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html).

Besides, [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) can provide you a way to access all data from the application state when trigerring actions:

```
(dispatch, getState) => {
  ...
};
```

Otherwise, you can import redux actions any where to have an action for a particular reducer trigger the action from another reducer.

This ways, the "composition" approach resolves all use cases.